# How to store "complex" data structure as a Persistent Data Structures using ethereum & serpent

Tags: python, dictionary, ethereum, complex-data-types, serpent

My work is concerning [Smart Contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_contract) dev. using [(py)ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum) and [serpent](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Serpent),

When reading "[A Programmer’s Guide to Ethereum and Serpent](https://mc2-umd.github.io/ethereumlab/docs/serpent_tutorial.pdf)", I saw on point 5.9 that :

> [...] Persistent data structures can be declared using the data declaration. This allows for the
>   declaration of arrays and tuples. [...]

and:

> [...] For simple storage, self.storage[]
>   is useful, but for larger contracts, we recommend the use of data (unless you need a key-
>   value storage, of course) [...]

Code example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import serpent
from ethereum import tester, utils, abi

serpent_code = '''
data mystorage[]


def test_data_storage(key,value):
    if not self.mystorage[key]:
        self.mystorage[key]=value
        return(1)
    else:
        return(0)


def get_value_mystorage(key):
    if not self.mystorage[key]:
        return(0)
    else:
        return(self.mystorage[key])



def test_self_storage(key,value):
    if not self.storage[key]:
        self.storage[key]=value
        return(1)
    else:
        return(0)


def get_value_self_storage(key):
    if not self.storage[key]:
        return(0)
    else:
        return(self.storage[key])

'''


s = tester.state()
c = s.abi_contract(serpent_code)

#example with self storage
c.test_self_storage("keyA",1)
print c.get_value_self_storage("keyA") #store and access data works in self.storage!

#example with mystorage
c.test_data_storage("keyB",2)
print c.get_value_mystorage("keyB") #store and access data works in data as persistant data storage!

#fail example with complex data
my_complex_data={"keyA":1,"keyB":2, "keyC":[1,2,3], "keyD":{"a":1,"b":2}}
c.test_data_storage("keyComplex",my_complex_data) 

#don't store anything because error:
# ethereum.abi.ValueOutOfBounds: {'keyC': [1, 2, 3], 'keyB': 2, 'keyA': 1, 'keyD': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}}
```

My question is : what is the best way and how to store complex data (*see my_complex_data* variable in code) like a dictionary which contain others dict. (or arrays as key value) as a persistant data structures ?

and does someone know if it is possible and how to store any class structure as a persistant data structures ?

Comment: May someone with at least 1500 reputation points could  add "serpent" tag pease.

Comment: _"The suggested edit queue is full."_ You'll need someone with 2k reputation.

Comment: @ASTEFANI, did you get anywhere with this on your own? I'd be really keen to hear what you found.

Comment: @samaspin, yes I finally found a "tricky/dirty" solution (please see my answer), but you may note that according to Vitalik tweet, it is better to migrate to Solidity or Vyper because Serpent is an "outdated tech" now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IMPORTANT** : Please note that according to [this Vitalik Tweet](https://twitter.com/VitalikButerin/status/886400133667201024), **[Serpent](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Serpent)** is now **an "outdated tech"**.

The Serpent `README` has been updated to :

> Being a low-level language, Serpent is NOT RECOMMENDED for building applications unless you really really know what you're doing. The creator recommends Solidity as a default choice, LLL if you want close-to-the-metal optimizations, or Vyper if you like its features though it is still experimental.

If you want to code Ethereum contracts from Python in order to release a production product, start to think about to migrate to [Solidity](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/) or [Vyper](https://github.com/ethereum/vyper) (which is still a "New experimental programming language")

---

Concerning my question, I finaly found a (tricky/dirty) solution, which consist of encoding the complex data before pushing it to the persistant data storage, then decoding after retrieving data from the storage.

Please see updated code bellow:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import serpent
import json,math
from ethereum import tester, utils, abi

serpent_code = '''
data mystorage[]


def test_data_storage(key,value):
    if not self.mystorage[key]:
        self.mystorage[key]=value
        return(1)
    else:
        return(0)


def get_value_mystorage(key):
    if not self.mystorage[key]:
        return(0)
    else:
        return(self.mystorage[key])



def test_self_storage(key,value):
    if not self.storage[key]:
        self.storage[key]=value
        return(1)
    else:
        return(0)



def rebuild_complex_data_storage(key):
    if not self.storage[key]:
        return(0)

def get_value_self_storage(key):
    if not self.storage[key]:
        return(0)
    else:
        return(self.storage[key])


def put_complex_data_storage(key,value=""):
    self.storage[key]=value


def get_complex_data_storage(key):
    return(self.storage[key])



'''


s = tester.state()
c = s.abi_contract(serpent_code)

#example with self storage
c.test_self_storage("keyA",1)
print c.get_value_self_storage("keyA") #store and access data works in self.storage!

#example with mystorage
c.test_data_storage("keyB",2)
print c.get_value_mystorage("keyB") #store and access data works in data as persistant data storage!

start_block="99699"

def block_chain_encode(c,key,my_complex_data):

    #ENCODE PART

    global start_block

    print "\n","*","ENCODE","*"

    #fail example with complex data
    my_complex_data_json_format=unicode(json.dumps(my_complex_data))

    int_str=start_block
    for each in my_complex_data_json_format:
        int_str=int_str+ str(ord(each)).zfill(4)
    int_str=int_str+start_block
    print int_str
    #toHex = lambda x:"".join([hex(ord(c))[2:].zfill(2) for c in x])
    print "need to declare 32 bit words", math.ceil(len(int_str)/32.),"times"
    #max 32 char for each key

    max_size=int(math.ceil(len(int_str)/32.))
    for i in range(0,max_size):
        block_content=int_str[i*32:(i+1)*32]
        print "block",i," content",block_content
        if i==0:
            c.test_data_storage("keyComplex_len",max_size)

        key="keyComplex_"+str(i).zfill(3)
        res=c.test_data_storage(key,int(block_content)) #store block part in block chain
        print " - substorage",key,"",

    #print "data storage part is done !"
    return 1

def block_chain_decode(c,key):

    #DECODE PART

    global start_block
    print "\n","*","DECODE","*"


    int_str=""
    lenght= c.get_value_mystorage("keyComplex_len") #get lenght to know how many block we need to get for all data from block chain
    for i in range(0,lenght):
        key="keyComplex_"+str(i).zfill(3)
        print key,c.get_value_mystorage(key)
        int_str=int_str+str(c.get_value_mystorage(key))

    content_=""
    sp_int_str= int_str.split(start_block)
    if len(sp_int_str)==3:
        if sp_int_str[-1]==sp_int_str[0] and sp_int_str[0]=="":
            print "ok"
            content_=sp_int_str[1]

    js_str=""
    if content_!="":
        for i in range(0,int(len(content_)/4.)):
            js_str+=chr(int(content_[i*4:(i+1)*4])) #recover char from asci code
    my_complex_data=json.loads(js_str)

    return my_complex_data

#define complex data
my_complex_data={"keyA":1,"keyB":2, "keyC":[1,2,3], "keyD":{"a":1,"b":2}}
print "Initial complex data",my_complex_data

#encode and push to block chain
block_chain_encode(c,"keyComplex",my_complex_data)

#get complex variable from block chain
my_complex_data_back = block_chain_decode(c,"keyComplex")
#acces data
print my_complex_data_back["keyD"]["a"]+my_complex_data_back["keyD"]["b"]
print "Extracted complex data from blockchain",my_complex_data
print "Integrity test pass:",my_complex_data_back==my_complex_data
```

Which return:

```
1
2
Initial complex data {'keyC': [1, 2, 3], 'keyB': 2, 'keyA': 1, 'keyD': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}}

* ENCODE *
99699012300340107010101210067003400580032009100490044003200500044003200510093004400320034010701010121006600340058003200500044003200340107010101210065003400580032004900440032003401070101012100680034005800320123003400970034005800320049004400320034009800340058003200500125012599699
need to declare 32 bit words 9.0 times
block 0  content 99699012300340107010101210067003
 - substorage keyComplex_000  block 1  content 40058003200910049004400320050004
 - substorage keyComplex_001  block 2  content 40032005100930044003200340107010
 - substorage keyComplex_002  block 3  content 10121006600340058003200500044003
 - substorage keyComplex_003  block 4  content 20034010701010121006500340058003
 - substorage keyComplex_004  block 5  content 20049004400320034010701010121006
 - substorage keyComplex_005  block 6  content 80034005800320123003400970034005
 - substorage keyComplex_006  block 7  content 80032004900440032003400980034005
 - substorage keyComplex_007  block 8  content 8003200500125012599699
 - substorage keyComplex_008  
* DECODE *
keyComplex_000 99699012300340107010101210067003
keyComplex_001 40058003200910049004400320050004
keyComplex_002 40032005100930044003200340107010
keyComplex_003 10121006600340058003200500044003
keyComplex_004 20034010701010121006500340058003
keyComplex_005 20049004400320034010701010121006
keyComplex_006 80034005800320123003400970034005
keyComplex_007 80032004900440032003400980034005
keyComplex_008 8003200500125012599699
ok
3
Extracted complex data from blockchain {'keyC': [1, 2, 3], 'keyB': 2, 'keyA': 1, 'keyD': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}}
Integrity test pass: True
```